# how to load js file before </body> if div with particular class name exists on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load .js file before the `</body>` in footer only if div with particular class name exists on page. I found the div with class name using if condition. But I am not getting how to add script in footer of page with it.

Here is my if condition code

```
if ($("#world-map-markers")[0]){

} else {
    // Do something if class does not exist
}
```

I want to add this in static html page. There is no backend language.

Thanks

Comment: You can use your backend language if you have one.

Comment: no its an static html page

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function loadJS(file) {
    // DOM: Create the script element
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    // set the type attribute
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    // make the script element load file
    jsElm.src = file;
    // finally insert the element to the body element in order to load the script
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
</script>
```

Comment: will this code add script before closing body tag

Answer (score 0):

You may can do somthing like this.

> ```
> if ($("#world-map-markers")[0]){
>     $('footer').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/load.js"></script>');
> } else {
>     // Do something if class does not exist
> }
> ```

Comment: I want to add before closing body tag

Comment: You may can use .prepend() function instead of .append() .

Comment: Or take last one div which used just before </body> Like :- <div class="xyz">xyz</div></body> & then $('.xyz').append(.....)